# Почечно-клеточный или почечноклеточный?

Tags: орфография

Как пишется почечно-клеточный или почечноклеточный (рак)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

В медицинских справочниках и орфографических словарях в большинстве случаев пишется через дефис.

[рак почечно-клеточный | tolkslovar.ru](http://tolkslovar.ru/r10609.html)

[рак почечно-клеточный | academic.ru](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/medic2/39230) Большой медицинский словарь:
рак почечно-клеточный

На какое правило ссылается редактор? Возможно, на следующее:

Пишутся слитно сложные имена прилагательные,образованные из сочетаний слов, по своему значению подчиненных одно другому, например:железнодорожный (железная дорога), народнохозяйственный (народное хозяйство).

Почечноклеточный = почечная клетка, клетка чего? почки. Но это формальный подход, видимо, не устраивающий медиков. Это вполне объяснимо, ведь речь идёт не о раке клетки почки, а о раке всей почки на уровне клетки эпителия, т.е. он почечный и клеточный, начинающийся на уровне клетки.

В правилах написано:

Примечание 1. Прилагательные, образованные из двух или более основ, не подходящие под перечисленные правила, пишутся через дефис, например: литературно-художественный (альманах), политико-массовая (работа),словарно-технический (отдел), подзолисто-болотный, рыхло-комковато-пылеватый, удлиненно-ланцетовидный.

Прямо этот случай не подходит ни под одно из условий(не подчинительное словосоч., не однородные прилагательные, не оттенок,), следовательно, пишем через дефис(полуслитное написание)

Comment: *Но это формальный подход, видимо, не устраивающий медиков* - Людмила, боюсь, дело в другом. Существует клеточные и неклеточные разновидности рака. Т. е. опухоли, имеющие клеточную и неклеточную структуру.  Не знаю, насколько это имеет отношение к орфографии, но - на мой вкус - это исключает слитное написание, здесь нет логического подчинения.

Comment: Так и я говорю: "Прямо этот случай не подходит ни под одно из условий(не подчинительное словосоч., не однородные прилагательные, не оттенок,), следовательно, пишем через дефис(полуслитное написание)"

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **почечно-клеточный.** Это терминология, разновидность клеточного рака: базально-клеточный, печеночно-клеточный.

Сложное прилагательное составлено из основ  двух прилагательных (неоднородное сочинение основ прилагательных).

**Дополнение**

В принципе **слитное написание термина вполне допустимо** (возможно, это общая тенденция в современной медицинской терминологии).

Способ образования сложного прилагательного – **чистое (бессуффиксальное) сложение** первой основы и опорного прилагательного. Эта первая основа в данном случае выполняет роль классификатора клеточных заболеваний по месту расположения.

**Пример** (тот диагноз, **который пишут медики**, а не тот, который исправляют  редакторы по общим орфографическим  правилам):

Мне 52 года, **17.02.09** мне удалили левую почку. Диагноз: заболевание левой почки St 4, кл. гр3. **Почечноклеточный рак**, светлоклеточный вариант с очагами кровоизлияния. [Рак почки | travolekar.ru](http://www.travolekar.ru/forum/read.php?id_forum=6&id_theme=1162)

**Скорее всего, меняется терминология,** дефисное написание оценивается как неудобное для записи подобных диагнозов. Идет переходный период от старой формы к новой форме, поэтому надо смотреть в **новейшей** медицинской литературе. А правила русского языка **допускают термины  со слитным написанием**, например: **старославянский и церковнославянский язык.**

**Другие примеры** (с дефисным написанием диагноза):

- [Лечение (химиотерапия) рака почки | medicinform.net](http://www.medicinform.net/rak/rakob17_6_13.htm)
- [Почечноклеочный рак (ПКР) | chemotherapy.ru](http://chemotherapy.ru/pochechnokletochniy_/index.html)

Comment: спасибо, так и писала, но редактор в издательстве ссылается на какое-то правило русского языка, в соответствии с которым нужно писать слитно

Comment: У Розенталя допускается как слитное, так и раздельное написание терминов, они у него даются списком http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49#pp49 пункты 2 и 12., поэтому должно быть общепринятое написание в медицине. Мне кажется, что дефисное написание в текстах встречается чаще  (из словаря: пищеводо-кишечный, плече-шейный, подвздошно-рёберный).

Comment: Но возможно ведомственные специалисты решили изменить орфографию, так как теоретически  (в общем случае) правило допускает обе формы.  Может быть, решили разграничить  однородное и неоднородное сочинение: почечно-печеночный (можно вставить союз и) и почечноклеточный (нельзя вставить союз И).

Comment: @Валерия *но редактор в издательстве ссылается на какое-то правило русского языка, в соответствии с которым нужно писать слитно* - а назвать это правило он отказывается?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, редактор ошибается. 
Вообще это тот нечастый случай, когда орфография определяется правильным пониманием термина.
Я не специалист, но насколько могу судить, здесь нет того, о чем говорит Людмила, т. е. логического подчинения. Речь не о клетках почки, имеется в виду клеточная разновидность рака, а почка - место локализации опухоли. упоминается еще базально-клеточный рак (кожи) - и всё. А вот рак легкого чаще всего - неклеточный. 
Если я всё правильно понимаю (***если!***), то слитное написание просто невозможно. 
Поэтому я рекомендую именно дефисное. ***Почечно-клеточный***. Правило на этот случай вам известно, надеюсь.